# Setting TimeOut for a function

Tags: javascript, html, canvas

Currently my sprite animation on my canvas will clear away the sprite image before the next sprite image appear to create an animated sprite. But recently I added a ripple function on to it, and everytime i click on the canvas a ripple effect will be form. But the screen will be blinking non-stop, due to the clearing away of the sprite images.

Do I have to set a TimeOut at this code? (Line 261 & 261)

```
setInterval(run, delay);
}
```

It's for the ripple function.

Answer (score 0):

Here' the code:

```
setTimeout(function(){

   // Your function

}, 2000);   // Set time in milliseconds
```